# How do I book without forced penalty?

Tags: tickets

I have a question about flying US Air internationally.  I am planning a trip with a return in June 2016.  The airline is not scheduling that far in advance and doesn't offer one way tickets.  This forces me to pay a $300 penalty to change my return flight.  Is there any other alternative?

Comment: Most airline tickets don't permit a return date >365 days from the outbound, so you might be out of luck

Answer (score 1):

The only other alternative is an "open return", where you don't specify the return flight, essentially giving you an undated return ticket that you can book a light with later. You are usually paying a premium for open returns, and I would expect it to cost you #300 extra or more, so you probably aren't saving anything by going that route.